# How do I extract the name of a parent directory from a directory name?

Tags: perl

Basically I have an environment variable which stores a location of a directory as given below

```
export MYPATH=/home/test/mysamplepath
```

Now in Perl script I want to know one path above that directory either using a function or some expression through which last part can be remove i.e. something like below

```
$myNewPath = '/home/test'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux or Unix based systems you can read the environment variable like this and then cut the needed rest of the path with a regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $path =  $ENV{'MYPATH'};
$path =~ s/^(\/.+)\/.+\/?$/$1/;
print $path . "\n";
```

Answer (score 6):

```
use File::Basename;
my $myNewPath = dirname($ENV{MYPATH});
```

Answer (score 0):

my $mynewpath = $oldpath =~ /(.+?)/\w+/;
Try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can match the path with regular expression:

```
if($line =~ /export\s\$MYPATH=(.*)(?<!\\)\//){
  $new_path = $1;
}
```

This also works if you have escaped `\` in your url.